# Ampersand and anchor element

Tags: sass

I have a anchor element that sometimes also has a class:

```
<a href="#" class="btn"></a>
```

I wish to target this in sass to override css rules on anchor tags, I've tried:

```
a {
    color: red;
}

.btn {
    & a {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

But with no luck.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to target anchor tags with the class `.btn` you can do this...

```
a {

    &.btn {

        // styles here
    }
}
```